# Getting the row culprit of an insertion failure

Tags: soql, exception

Sometimes some of my orders and contracts are not define in the same date terms. That causes my system to throw an exception as follows:

> Message:  Insert failed. First exception on row 8; first error:
>   FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Order Start Date can't be earlier than the
>   contract's start date.: Order Start Date: [EffectiveDate

The message is very clear; however the default exception message does not specify which row is having the issue while trying to commit the work.

I am committing as follows:

```
List<Order> orderToInsertList = new List<Order>();

// doing some processing

insert orderToInsertList;
```

Is there any way I can get the data of row culprit of the exception?

Comment: It says, "row 8", probably thats what you are looking for?

Comment: It tells the row number; however, I would like to have access to the values of that particular row so that I can pinpoint the culprit of the exception.

Comment: Are you using insert/update keywords or using Database methods?

Comment: I am using the insert/update keywords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Database.methods for this. Database methods returns us Saveresult which tells us about rows which were problematic.

```
List<Sobject> toBeinserted;// = your records to be inserted;
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();

Database.SaveResult [] sresultResultArray = Database.insert(toBeinserted,false);
List<Integer> errorRows = new List<Integer>();
for(Integer i=0; i < sresultResultArray.size();i++){
    Database.SaveResult sr = sresultResultArray[i];
    if(!sr.success){
        errorRows.add(i);
    }
}

if(errorRows.size()>0){
    //This means there was an error. Lets do roll back
    Database.rollback(sp); //To stop partial commits
    //errorRows contains the rows in toBeinserted which were probelematic
    System.debug(errorRows );

}
```

> The optional allOrNone parameter specifies whether the operation
>   allows partial success. If you specify false for this parameter and a
>   record fails, the remainder of the DML operation can still succeed.
>   This method returns a result object that can be used to verify which
>   records succeeded, which failed, and why. If the parameter is not set
>   or is set true, an exception is thrown if the method is not
>   successful.

You can also use your Map-like data structure to store rowNumer vs ErrorMessage encountered.

**NOTE :** We only get Save result when we enable partial commit, this can sometimes be not desired, so make sure you do a ROLLBACK, to reach the previous state,

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm

Answer (score 4):

> Use Database Class methods to insert the Record and then you can
>   easily be identified which records are failing.

Using Database method you can also partially commit the data into the system means only failed records will get inserted into the system.

**Example**

> The following example shows how to obtain and iterate through the
>   returned Database.SaveResult objects. It inserts two accounts using
>   Database.insert with a false second parameter to allow partial
>   processing of records on failure.

```
// Create two accounts, one of which is missing a required field
Account[] accts = new List<Account>{
    new Account(Name='Account1'),
    new Account()};
Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(accts, false);

// Iterate through each returned result
for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList) {
    if (!sr.isSuccess()) {
        // Operation failed, so get all errors                
        for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
            System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
            System.debug('Fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
        }
    }
}
```

Source: - [Database Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_database_error.htm)